# How to using it(TimeTask) in xamarin.android (java to c#)

Tags: xamarin.android

```
Timer timer = new Timer();  
timer.schedule(new TimerTask()  
{  
   public void run()  
   {  
      InputMethodManager inputManager =(InputMethodManager)editText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
      inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, 0);  
     }  
 }, 998);
```

**this is java**
**
I want to delay the keyboard pop-up**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity: IRunnable{
    Android.OS.Handler _handler;

    protected void MethodXY(){
        _handler = new Android.OS.Handler();
        _handler.PostDelayed(this, 998);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _handler.RemoveCallbacks(this);
        InputMethodManager inputManager =(InputMethodManager)editText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
  inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, 0); 
    }
}
```

Alternative: (e.g. you are using more than one Handler in your activity)

```
public class MyActivity: IRunnable{

    protected void MethodXY(){
        Android.OS.Handler handler = new Android.OS.Handler();
        handler.PostDelayed(new DelayedKeyboardRunnable(handler, editText), 998);
    }

    private class DelayedKeyboardRunnable: Java.Lang.Object, IRunnable
    {
            EditText _et;
            Android.OS.Handler _handler;

            public DelayedKeyboardRunnable(Android.OS.Handler handler, EditText et)
            {
                _handler = handler;
                _et = et;
            }

            public void Run()
            {
                _handler.RemoveCallbacks(this);
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)_et.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
                inputManager.showSoftInput(_et, 0); 
            }
    }
}
```